# List Updating a value after Insert

Tags: c#, linq

i have a issue, I want to Update a value to element which is getting added in a list.

With generic example:-

I have a Model Object:-

```
public class Model
{
    public int ModelProperty1 { get; set; }

    public int ModelProperty2 { get; set; }

    public int ModelPropertyStatus { get; set; }
}
```

I have a DTO Object:-

```
 public class DTO
{
    public int DTOProperty1 { get; set; }

    public int DTOProperty2 { get; set; }

    public int DTOPropertyStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in my Controller i have a List which adds Model object:-

```
List<Model> _listOfModel = new List<Model>();
```

Secondly, i have created a mapping method which maps my Model & DTO

```
 private Model MapDTOToModel(DTO dto)
    {
        return new Model
        {
            ModelProperty1 = dto.DTOProperty1,
            ModelProperty2 = dto.DTOProperty2
        };
    }
```

Coming to my Issue:-
I want something like this to work:-
//I want a piece of code that Updates my ModelPropertyStatus  after it gets inserted to //List

```
    _listOfModel.Add(new Model() { ModelPropertyStatus = 1 });
```

//Here is the piece of code i want to convert:-

```
            Model model = new Model();
        model.ModelPropertyStatus = 1;
        _listOfModel.Add(MapDTOToModel(model));
```

To be specific(Updated)
I want something like this:-

```
_listOfModel.Add(MapDTOToModel() { ModelPropertyStatus = 1 });
```

Any Suggestions??

Comment: How do you want to add items? Where is the IEnumerable to which you want to perform some action?

Comment: basically, I want to Update "ModelPropertyStatus" When it gets added to the list after MapDTOToModel(model).
Hope this clarifies your issue.

Comment: Why can't you update the status immediately prior or after the add?

Comment: Or why don't you set `ModelPropertyStatus` in `MapDTOToModel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for an [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx):

> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

---

Here's an example:

```
public class Model
{
    public int ModelProperty1 { get; set; }
    public int ModelProperty2 { get; set; }
    public int ModelPropertyStatus { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    ObservableCollection<Model> _listOfModel = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
    _listOfModel.CollectionChanged += (s, o) =>
    {
        foreach (var m in o.NewItems)
            ((Model)m).ModelPropertyStatus = 1;
    };

    var model = new Model();

    Console.WriteLine("Before add: " + model.ModelPropertyStatus.ToString());

    _listOfModel.Add(model);

    Console.WriteLine("After add: " + model.ModelPropertyStatus.ToString());
}
```

output:

> Before add: 0
>   After add: 1

---

As you can see, using the `CollectionChanged` event, the property gets updatet during the insert.

Comment: Thanks Dominic, just provide me a piece of suggestion :-
Is it possible to have something like

_listOfModel.Add(MapDTOToModel() { ModelPropertyStatus = 1 });

where MapDTOToModel() returns me a Model object....

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want. In your example code, you create a `new Model()`, but your `MapDTOToModel` method takes an `DTO` as argument. If you want to manually change the `ModelPropertyStatus` before adding, then why not just set it *before* adding the model?